# Subprocess arp -a yielding less results than cmd arp -a

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

The below code produces a lesser ip yield than doing `arp -a` in `cmd`

```
arpA_req = Popen('arp -a', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

line = arpA_req.stdout.readline().decode('ascii').rsplit()
print(line)
```

Does anyone know why this may be?  And if it's a common issue, how can I obtain a fuller ip list?

Comment: what does it produce?

Comment: You only read 1 line ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As wim pointed out, [readline()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) only reads one line. 
To read all the output, one way is to call [communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
import subprocess
PIPE, STDOUT = subprocess.PIPE, subprocess.STDOUT
arpA_req = subprocess.Popen(
    ['arp', '-a'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
out, err = arpA_req.communicate()
print(out)
```

Or, to process one line at a time, a standard idiom is to use [iter(func, stop_value)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter):

```
for line in iter(arpA_req.stdout.readline, ''):
    print(line)
```